# Centos 7 Port 80 blocked even after opening via firewall-cmd

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, httpd, firewalld, port-80

I'm trying to set up a new Centos 7 web server, and can't seem to get port 80 open to the outside. Apache is installed and running. I'm just trying to get the startup page so that I can move on with installs and configs. Unfortunately, I am just getting timeouts when browsing to the IP as it seems port 80 is inaccessible.

I opened up the port in the firewall...

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --query-port=80/tcp
yes

$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
  public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 80/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

What the heck am I missing? Even if I turn the firewall off, I still get timeouts.

```
$ telnet 70.61.231.4 80
Trying 70.61.231.4...
telnet: connect to address 70.61.231.4: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Could it be something with Apache instead of the firewall?

EDIT: Adding netstat details and curl results...

```
$ sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN      25835/httpd


$ curl 127.0.0.1
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Apache HTTP Server Test Page powered by CentOS</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: It could be apache, yes.  See if:
  netstat -tlnp
shows anything actually listening on port 80

Comment: Check the cable modem and/or router attached to it, and call Time Warner to ensure they haven't blocked this port.

Comment: Thanks guys. I added some details to the question to show that the server is listening on port 80, and Apache seems to be working, as it is returning the Apache test page via curl on localhost. I will have to check to see if ISP has anything to do with port 80 being blocked.

Comment: You were correct Michael. It was Time Warner. I thought he had this server in his data center, but it was in his office while being built out.